# Iterating through list, ignoring duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, iteration

I've written a program that attempts to find a series of letters (toBeFound - these letters represent a word) in a list of letters (letterList), however it refuses to acknowledge the current series of 3 letters as it counts the 'I' in the first list twice, adding it to the duplicate list.

Currently this code returns "incorrect", when it should return "correct".

```
letterList= ['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E']
toBeFound = ['F', 'I', 'X']

List = []
for i in toBeFound[:]:
    for l in letterList[:]:
        if l== i:
            letterList.remove(l)
            List.append(i)
if List == toBeFound:
    print("Correct.")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
```

letterList and toBeFound are sample values, the letters in each can be anything. I can't manage to iterate through the code and successfully ensure that duplicates are ignored. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not make the letterList a set?

Comment: My guess is relative order is important.

Comment: @AustinStehling set is unordered, it looks like his problem needs letters to be ordered. I would use a dictionary with letters as key, and count as value to fix

Comment: I agree with @AustinStehling . Casting the list to a set will remove the duplicates and if you need to you can cast it back to a list.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the condition from `if l==i` to `if l==i and not l in List:`.

Comment: I ran the code exactly as the OP has it, and it did return "correct"

Comment: @AustinStehling would you be able to possibly give an example of this? What would be contained within the set?

Comment: @bertew Do you only want to remove _consecutive duplicates_ (ones beside each other), or does the ordering of the sublist not matter at all? i.e. should `['F', 'I', 'X']` in `['X', 'X', 'F', 'I']` be true?

Comment: @bertew I posted the solution in the answer section.

Comment: It really seems an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).What are you trying to achieve? *If the list1 contains the char in list2 in that order*? `"".join(list2) in "".join(list1)`. *If list2 element are in list1*? `all([x in list1 for x in list2])` or what else?

Comment: @miradulo yes, any combination should be True

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking to see if `toBeFound` is a *subset* of `letterList`, right?

That is a hint to use `set`s:

```
In [1]: letters = set(['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E'])

In [2]: find = set(['F', 'I', 'X'])

In [3]: find.issubset(letters)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: find <= letters
Out[4]: True
```

(BTW, [3] and [4] are different notations for the same operator.)

Comment: im not sure. it looks like they are looking for a sublist not a subset. if toBeFound for example contains a word like 'hello' then you cant use subsets to find it. you would be stuck with 'helo'

Comment: The OP states that FIX should be a match for FIIXORE. That rules out sublists.

Comment: See i don't think I agree. In the example given FIX is the desired word and the input is FIIXORE. There are no duplicates in the desired word. What I'm suggesting is if you are given HELLO as the desired word with an input of HEMLALOWL you would presumably still want that input to be valid since it contains HELLO in order.

Comment: According to a comment from the OP, order doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Fair enough, The approach i went with doesn't actually care about order, but im still pretty sure its a sublist not a subset based on the example

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem. Please try it and let me know

```
letterList= ['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E']
toBeFound = ['F', 'I', 'X']

found_list = [i for i in toBeFound if i in letterList]

print("Correct" if toBeFound == found_list else "Incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the initial list a set, but if you want to look up a word like 'hello' it wont work because you'll need both l's.

One way to solve this is to use a dictionary to check and see how we are doing so far.

```
letterList = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'X', 'L', 'I', 'O']
toBeFound = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']

# build dictionary to hold our desired letters and their counts
toBeFoundDict = {}
for i in toBeFound:
    if i in toBeFoundDict:
        toBeFoundDict[i] += 1
    else:
        toBeFoundDict[i] = 1

letterListDict = {} # dictionary that holds values from input
output_list = [] # dont use list its a reserved word
for letter in letterList:
    if letter in letterListDict: # already in dictionary

        # if we dont have too many of the letter add it
        if letterListDict[letter] < toBeFoundDict[letter]:
            output_list.append(letter)

        # update the dictionary
        letterListDict[letter] += 1


    else: # not in dictionary so lets add it

        letterListDict[letter] = 1

        if letter in toBeFoundDict:
            output_list.append(letter)



if output_list == toBeFound:
    print('Success')
else:
    print('fail')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: (I tested in python3.6)

```
import collections
letterList= ['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E']
toBeFound = ['F', 'I', 'X']
collections.Counter(letterList)
a=collections.Counter(letterList) # print(a) does not show order
                              # but a.keys() has order preserved
final = [i for i in a.keys() if i in toBeFound]
if final == toBeFound:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to check if letterList has the letters of toBeFound in the specified order and ignoring repeating letters, this would be a simple variation on the old "file match" algorithm.  You could implement it in a non-destructive function like this:

```
def letterMatch(letterList,toBeFound):
    i= 0
    for letter in letterList:
        if letter == toBeFound[i] : i += 1
        elif i > 0 and letter != toBeFound[i-1] : break
        if i == len(toBeFound)    : return True
    return False

letterMatch(['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E'],['F', 'I', 'X'])
# returns True
```

On the other hand, if what you're looking for is testing if letterList has all the letters needed to form toBeFound (in any order), then the logic is much simpler as you only need to "check out" the letters of toBeFound using the ones in letterList:

```
def lettermatch(letterList,toBeFound):
    missing = toBeFound.copy()
    for letter in letterList:
        if letter in missing : missing.remove(letter)
    return not missing
```

Answer (score -1):

As requested.

```
letterList= ['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E']
toBeFound = ['F', 'I', 'X']

List = []
for i in toBeFound[:]:
    for l in set(letterList):
        if l== i:
            List.append(i)
if List == toBeFound:
    print("Correct.")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
```

This prints correct. I made the letterList a set! Hope it helps.

Comment: `letterList.remove(l)` doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: Yes you are definitely correct. He asked if I could show him what I meant by making a set and missed that. @pault. Otherwise this returns the answer he is looking for.

Answer (score -2):

One simple way is to just iterate through `toBeFound`, and look for each element in `letterList`.

```
letterList= ['F','I',  'I',  'X',  'O',  'R',  'E']
toBeFound = ['F', 'I', 'X']

found = False
for x in letterList:
    if x not in toBeFound:
        found = False
        break

if found:
   print("Correct.")
else:
   print("Incorrect.")
```

Comment: Why not just use list comprehension as found = [i for i in toBeFound if i in letterList]

Comment: Yes, that is another way. Though it would require some more logic to print incorrect or correct.